# Visual Studio CTRL + F but how to work it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, full-text-search, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search selection, current documet, all open documents etc. But is there a way to work witch search bar only with keyboard? For example to switch between searching option, expand the search bar etc.?

Comment: This would be better on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if you want to have a single KB shortcut for every type of search (current document, all open docs, etc). But after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times until you navigate to the search scope DDL and then press <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> to select the needed option.

Will it be easier for you than using the mouse? :)